# Running code from VBA to VBScript back to VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to figure out a way to call a `VBScript` function using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) in `Excel`, and then pass a value back to [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba). See below

`VBA` within Excel

```
    Sub RunTest()
    Dim objString as String

    'Begin Pseudocode
    objString = Call VBScript Function Test()
    'End Pseudocode

    MsgBox objString `from VBS
    End Sub
```

`VBScript`

```
    Function Test
    Test = "Hello World"
    End Function
```

I know this may seem strange because I could just write the function in VBA, but we had an office patch pushed out and it completely killed the functionality of one of my macros for some reason. Strange thing is, I can run the exact same code within any other office program, just not excel. As a work around, I moved the function that crashes excel to word and I pull it using application.run, but I prefer to not have to do that, as opening a the word application to run my macro slows my process way down.

Any help is appreciated, thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I feel a litte dirty :)

This code has two key parts:

- the `vbs` Uses `GetObject` and the full host workbook path to re-attach to the file containing the `VBA` that called the `VBS`
- the `VBS` adds a value to a specific worksheet in the host `VBA` file to trigger the `Worksheet_Change` event to fire, running `VBA` with the string passed from the `VBS`.

**Step 1:  Regular Excel code module**

```
Sub VBA_to_VBS_to_VBA()
Shell "wscript c:\temp\myvbs.vbs", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

**Step 2:  *myvbs***

```
Dim xlApp
Dim xlSht
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject("c:\temp\mybook.xlsx").Application
Set xlSht = xlApp.Sheets("vbs sheet")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not xlSht Is Nothing Then
xlSht.Range("A1").Value = "hello world"
Else
wscript.echo "sheet not found"
End If
```

**Step 3:  Sheet code for *vbs sheet* in your Excel File**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox [a1].Value, vbCritical, "VBS insertion"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tronald did you ever try this?

Comment: I don’t know why I never noticed this was left unchecked. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

Try syntax like:

```
Sub Test()
    Shell "cscript c:\TestFolder\sample.vbs", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer as well. I must have worded my question bad as you and Brett gave the same answer. I know I can run the script from VBA but what I would like to do is call a specific function within the script and set my string object within VBA equal to the result of the function contained in the script. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Tronald:  I have never done this, but both VBA and VBScript can read/write **Registry keys**.  You could design and implement an interface using them.

Comment: @tronald can't you run all of this - including automating VBA - from the VbS directly, rather than looking to switch between the two

Comment: @brettdj, that would be the 'makes sense' route if i hadn't already built a giant beast withing VBA. I have a few programs that that worked great for years. Last week an update to office was pushed over our network and now excel closes when I log into my database at work through excel. I can use the same code within word or any other office product and it works fine, but excel just closes when it runs it's so strange. The people who designed the database no longer offer SDK support and my chances of getting the network admins to remove the patch or getting Microsoft to fix what they broke is 0

Comment: I ran out of characters so continuing on.... So as a temporary work around i sent the database login sub to word. I open a word application from excel, run the code in word as a function then set my login object in Excel = to the function that ran in Word. It works fine, but opening word takes up far more memory that running a simple script. If I can figure out how to do a simple hello world like described above, I can figure out this workaround I need.