# Excel VBA file open by same vs other user

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a bit of code for a company who will be using it on their network. I'm not on a network like theirs to be able to test, so I'm checking in to try and make sure the code is right first time!

The workbook will interact with other worksheets on their network in various ways, and essentially I need to be able to check if:

1. The target workbook is already open on their own system, and
   ideally:

   - Whether it is open in the same Excel instance, or
   - Whether is is open in a separate instance *(I believe this could
     require different actions for copying and pasting ranges, saving etc
     which I need to learn more about)*
2. The target workbook is open by another network user (so presume it would only open as read-only)

I've come across lots of stuff about checking if a workbook is already open, eg: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291295

But I haven't found anything that clearly differentiates between the two scenarios I explained above.

Thank you

*Update*

I am now using:

```
Function IsFileOpenInInstance(FileName As String) 
 Dim ShortFileName As String
 Dim ValidOpenFile As Boolean
 Dim ErrNum As Integer 
 On Error Resume Next 
 ShortFileName = Dir(FileName)
 If FileName = Workbooks(ShortFileName).FullName Then  ValidOpenFile = True 
 ErrNum = Err 
 On Error GoTo 0
 If ErrNum <> 0 Then
     IsFileOpenInInstance = False
 Else 
     IsFileOpenInInstance = ValidOpenFile
 End If
 End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I couldn't find what was the relevant code in the link you sent though. Confused me a fair bit!

Answer (score 1):

1. Because of how Excel macros are resolved, Excel workbooks within a single instance are distinguished by unqualified name (file name without full path).

   Try accessing `Workbooks("File Name.xls")` to see if the workbook is loaded within current instance, and if it is, check `FullName` to see if it is indeed the right one.

   It does not make a difference, operation-wise, whether or not two workbooks are opened in different instances. Getting a pointer to another instance, however, may be problematic and I don't recommend this (e.g. if you call `GetObject("File Name.xls")`, it can return your instance of Excel, not the other one, even if you don't have the file opened). You should work on assumption that all required workbooks are opened in the same instance.
2. It does not make a difference whether you or another user has opened a workbook. If you try to open the same workbook in another instance of Excel, it will tell you it is blocked same way as if it was opened by someone else.

Comment: (2) is correct, but I think Basil wants to differentiate between the file being opened by the same user, or someone else. On (1), if you know the workbook name, `GetObject` can be used to hook into the instance that has this workook open.

Comment: @brettdj As I understood the point of (2) was that when another user opens a file it becomes read-only for you. It's true, but if you open the file, it becomes read-only too, so from read-only-ness point of view, it doesn't matter who opened the file. As for `GetObject`, it may return either instance, and in fact when I tested it it returned the instance in which I was calling it, not the one that had the file opened. This is different from your linked code, where you call GetObject from a script, not from an Excel instance.

Comment: Yes, it will be read-only, but presumably the OP wants to distinguish between a local readonly versus network read-only as the courses of action open are different. On your GetObject testing, did you use the full path name (sample [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849853/running-code-from-vba-to-vbscript-back-to-vba)?)

Comment: @brettdj Yes I did use the full path. I had two instances of Excel, one with the file currently opened, one with the file previously opened but now closed. The code was in the latter instance.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried this on xl2010 and couldn't replicate this behaviour. Is the file that was opened, now closed, still shown in the VBA Editor in that instance?

Comment: @brettdj No, the file is not shown. The point is, `GetObject` is not reliable is this sense by design. Try this: Double-click the file to create an Excel instance. Launch another instance, Open that file in it too (you should get a read-only warning). In VBA editors of both instances execute `? getobject("C:\file.xls").application.hwnd`, note they return same number. Now close the file in the instance that reports itself as the file owner. Execute the code again in both instances. It will return the same number, even though the file is now closed in that instance, but opened in another.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Brett & Gserge. Based on your feedback GSerg, I'll treat 1)ii) the same as 2) and use the existing code I have. For 1)i) I've put this code together (next comment) and it seems to do the trick. Please let me know if I've missed anything. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it to show the code neatly:
`Function IsFileOpenInInstance(FileName As String)
 Dim ShortFileName As String
 Dim ValidOpenFile As Boolean
 Dim ErrNum As Integer
 On Error Resume Next
 ShortFileName = Dir(FileName)
 If FileName = Workbooks(ShortFileName).FullName Then ValidOpenFile = True
 ErrNum = Err
 On Error GoTo 0
 If ErrNum <> 0 Then
  IsFileOpenInInstance = False
 Else
  IsFileOpenInInstance = ValidOpenFile
 End If
End Function`

Comment: @user3701495 I have added the code you are now using to your initial question (I would run with the MSFT link you posted initially myself). It does make your question inconsistent if you are now happy to treat the file as being open locally or elsewhere on the network in the same way (so you may want to edit it :))

Comment: @gserg I tried your method (twice) in xl2010, and `GetObject` correctly updated `hwnd` when the first instance was closed. This worked both when just the original file was closed but the original instance left open, and when the original instance was also closed.

Comment: Hi Brett,
I only treat the case where the user has it open in a different instance as being the same as another user. Different code runs if the file open in the same instance. Thanks for raising the concern though. I've come across another issue in that it doesn't seem to give control back to the workbook. If I click on the control after it runs, it selects the object. Getting it to select e.g. cell B7 in VBA doesn't seem to work. I suspect it's because the original instance doesn't have the focus returned at that end. Probably a different question, but I'll try and do some more research