# How to run macro in already open multiple workbooks

Tags: vba

An application generates several csv files. I need to run my vba code(which may reside in a separate excel file and I can call it via a .vbs button) so that it loops through all the csv's (that are already open) and does its thing like sorting, formatting and saving as per my codes logic.

Comment: This question seems too vague, please add more details on what you are trying to do and how you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If all the workbooks are in the same instance of Excel (including the excel file with the sorting/formatting code), you can do

```
For Each Workbook In Application.Workbooks
    'do your thing
Next
```

If that is not the case, you should probably make that the case. If not possible, see [Can VBA Reach Across Instances of Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971473/can-vba-reach-across-instances-of-excel)

Comment: The above code is not working. It only works for the workbook that is active hence if I have 3 workbooks open in an instance of excel only in one workbook the code works. Yes all workbooks (the csv's that are generated one by one ) are in the same instance of excel. But the code is residing in a separate excel which can be called upon by a vb scrpit button.