# Assigning cell value from another workbook to my code

Tags: excel, vba

**Basically what I want to achieve is assigning the cell value from the other workbook into my code.**

- Customers send in a spreadsheet of goods they want to order and this spreadsheet is used for more than one purpose so it has many columns which are not needed for my purpose.
- So I created the macro to look up and give me the value from certain columns and spit out a CSV file.
- I then created a spreadsheet of my own with the column values all mapped out, I am trying to get the coding to lookup the cell value in my spreadsheet and knows which columns to be looking up on the customer spreadsheet.
- I want it so I can just go in and change the values in the cells on
  my spreadsheet instead of having to go into the coding and change the
  columns value in my code.

> ```
> ShipToSiteID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("Q" & counter))
> AltShipTo1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("G" & counter))
> AltShipTo2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("H" & counter))
> AltShipToCity = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("I" & counter))
> 'AltShipToState = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("I" & counter))
>  AltShipToZip = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("J" & counter))
> AltShipToCountry = "UNITED KINGDOM"
> RefNumber = counter - 1
>     UserId = LCase(Environ("username"))
>
> ShipToSiteID = Replace(ShipToSiteID + AltShipToZip, " ", "")
>
> Sheets(2).Select
>
>     Range("A" & counter - 1) = LineType & comma & RefNumber & comma & QName & comma & BlanketID _
>                                         & comma & BillToSiteID & comma & ShipToSiteID & comma & ContractID _
>                                         & comma & PONumber & comma & CaseID & comma & ShipVia & comma & RequiredDate _
>                                         & comma & Comments & comma & Priority & comma & TerminalID & comma _
>                                         & AltContactFirst & comma & AltContactLast & comma & AltPhone & comma _
>                                         & AltShipTo1 & comma & AltShipTo2 & comma & AltShipToCity & comma _
>                                         & AltShipToState & comma & AltShipToZip & comma & AltShipToCountry _
>                                         & comma & UserId & comma
> ```

Comment: And what is your question? Or what isn't working?

Comment: So at the moment in the code where it is pointing to the column Q,G,H,I,J. I want to change this so it looks up a value in another workbook. MyWorksheet lets say, Sheet(2) range ("H5") has the value Q in it and I want my code so the ShipToSiteID points at that cell and uses the value of that cell. So if the column parameter every changes I can go into MyWorksheet and change it rather than going through my coding and changing it.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions...

To reference a value in workbook2 on workbook1, the easiest way to do this would be to copy the worksheet from workbook2 to workbook1. Then you can reference the value by typing "=" in the cell, and clicking on the cell that you want to reference.

Referencing in VBA code gives you some more flexibility. I'd suggest checking [this good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10717999#10717999) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971473/can-vba-reach-across-instances-of-excel/3303016#3303016) for more info. This may be more along the lines of what you want.

Unfortunately, if you reference a value from workbook2 on workbook1, there is no easy way to change the value of workbook2 from workbook1.