# VBA returns error 1004 while trying to copy worksheet to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have question: while trying to copy a worksheet to another workbook I get an error (error  1004 ).
This is my code:

```
Sub CopyWorksheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim BonusRatesWB As Workbook
Dim appExcel  As Application

Set appExcel = New Application
appExcel.Visible = False
Set BonusRatesWB = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Documents\Overdraft\OVERDUE customers\HARD COLLECTION\Hard Collectors Bonus Calc\BonusRates\ProblemLoansOfficerBonusRates15Sep2017.xlsx")
With ThisWorkbook
    BonusRatesWB.Sheets(1).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
End With
BonusRatesWB.Close

appExcel.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

I assume there's something missing/wrong with my object variables, but I was unable to figure it out. Help would be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not setting `ThisWB` to anything after you `Dim` it

Comment: is there a good reason why you're opening a *new* instance of Excel.Application?

Comment: @DavidZemens I want to avoid screen flashing out while the code runs. I understand with ScreenUpdating=False it will still open the new window.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating` controls the screen "flashing". Normally (there may be exceptions) opening a workbook will exist in the *current* instance of Excel application. A new "window" but not a new "application". I think because you are opening the workbook explicitly in a new instance of Excel, that you cannot copy it this way. Can you try opening in same instance?

Comment: @DavidZemens it worked when I tried to open it in the same instance. But I don't get why wouldn't it work with a new instance.

Comment: It *would* work with a new instance - it's just that the new instance is overkill / not needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the answer/revision , it seems unnecessary to open a new instance of Excel.Application just to open/copy a worksheet (actually this is the source of your 1004 error, see below).

**Open it in the same instance**, incorporating the other answer as well:

```
Sub CopyWorksheet()    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim BonusRatesWB As Workbook
    Set BonusRatesWB = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Documents\Overdraft\OVERDUE customers\HARD COLLECTION\Hard Collectors Bonus Calc\BonusRates\ProblemLoansOfficerBonusRates15Sep2017.xlsx")
    With ThisWorkbook
        BonusRatesWB.Sheets(1).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        BonusRatesWB.Close 
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I don't think you `Copy` worksheet like this across two different Excel Applications, and that seems to be the source of the 1004 error.

> I don't get why wouldn't it work with a new instance

[This is by design limitation:](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-or-copy-worksheets-or-worksheet-data-47207967-bbb2-4e95-9b5c-3c174aa69328?CorrelationId=903ba078-dcfc-4422-b3f2-d11b8a6cf852&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP001217035#BM2)

> NOTE: You cannot move or copy worksheets between workbooks that are open in separate instances of Excel. If a workbook is opened in a separate instance of Excel — for example, this can happen when you open that workbook from a Windows SharePoint Services site — make sure that you open that workbook in the same instance of Excel instead by browsing to it in the Open dialog box (File tab, Open).

**If you *must* open in a new instance**, then you can use a workaround as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075427/copy-entire-worksheet-from-one-instance-of-excel-to-another), by simply saving the sheet to a new/temporary file, and then opening that from the origin instance of Excel, in order to copy/paste. It's more overhead, but if you need to do it that's the only way.

Comment: many thanks for your comprehensive support!

Answer (score 2):

change the Dim to this

```
Dim ThisWB As Workbook
```

and then add:

```
Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
```

Your `ThisWorkbook` object has been declared but not assigned a value, and to assign a value to an object, you need to use `Set [object] = [value expression]`.

This works IF AND ONLY IF `ThisWorkbook` is the `ActiveWorkbook` at runtime. Any other scenario will fail because you cannot assign *a different workbook object* to `ThisWorkbook` built in object.

Just use the built-in object, instead. You were getting a 1004 error because your `Sheets.Count` was qualified to the newly opened workbook, not `ThisWorkbook`, which will give an error if `BonusRatesWB.Sheets.Count > ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count`.  To avoid that, *always* qualify worksheets, ranges, etc., to their respective parent objects. Below using a `With ThisWorkbook` block:

```
Sub CopyWorksheet()    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim BonusRatesWB As Workbook
    Dim appExcel  As Application

    Set appExcel = New Application
    appExcel.Visible = False
    Set BonusRatesWB = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Documents\Overdraft\OVERDUE customers\HARD COLLECTION\Hard Collectors Bonus Calc\BonusRates\ProblemLoansOfficerBonusRates15Sep2017.xlsx")
    With ThisWorkbook
        BonusRatesWB.Sheets(1).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    End With
    BonusRatesWB.Close   

    appExcel.Quit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Or just omit that declaration altogether and use the built-in `ThisWorkbook` object -- assuming OP is running the code *from* the `ActiveWorkbook` there's no really good reason to `Dim` a variable to represent a static built-in object like `ThisWorkbook` ")

Comment: I agree... I thought about adding that in, but wanted to just keep it simple and show him that you have to Set an object after you Dim it.

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer. Unfortunately now I get error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error).

Comment: It's simpler not to `Dim` a variable that isn't really needed :) Your code will actually fail with a type mismatch if any other workbook is active at runtime.

Comment: @IvaBazhunaishvili I've fixed the answer and I think it will avoid the 1004 now. Please see revised answer/explanation.

Comment: @David Zemens this was just a snippet from another larger macro where I'd probably need to dim it. Can you suggest if it still fails in case I use ThisWorkbook ?

Comment: Why would you need to `Dim` it? If the code you provided is not a [mcve] of your actual problem, then you need to revise your question. As edited, the answer above explains *why* your code fails in both scenarios you described. It also explains that you need to actually `Set` object variables. If you `Dim` it, then you need to `Dim thisWB as Workbook` and then `Set thisWB = ActiveWorkbook`. That should allow for it to run against *any* active workbook.

Comment: @DavidZemens Many thanks for the thorough explanation. Now I understand that I have to set object variables. I used your example but the code still fails (with the same error). In my situation BonusRatesWB.Sheets.Count > ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count is not true, so the reason should be something different I guess.

Comment: @IvaBazhunaishvili can you revise your question to show the code you are currently attempting to use? I can't think of any obvious reasons why above code would fail with 1004, unless the destination workbook is protected in which case you may need to "unprotect" it before you can paste a new sheet in to it.

Comment: @IvaBazhunaishvili regardless, it's still a bad idea to code it that way because you can't guarantee the structure of two arbitrary workbooks will *always* be such to avoid this index error.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm using the exactly same code as you have suggested, therefore I don't really understand what to revise... (I'm a newby both to this forum and to VBA, so I might be getting your suggestion wrong).

Comment: FWIW I find it terribly confusing and bug-prone that `ThisWB` is assigned to `ActiveWorkbook` rather than `ThisWorkbook`; and if it's meant to be `ThisWorkbook`, then `ThisWB` isn't needed - just work with `ThisWorkbook` if that's the case.