# Reference workbooks between instances of Excel

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

long time user, first question.

So an internet site that my business used to get information on coal ship movements has recently been reworked, so I have to rework my program to scrape the ship information. I had been navigating to each port using button click events and using;
`Dim Table As Object, Set Table = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(11)`
to get the actual table. On the new site they have the option to export all ship movements to excel and it would be a lot quicker if I could automate the macro to get the excel files. To clarify I am just trying to get my program to go to this site; https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/, click on 'Ship Movements' up the top, click 'Tools', click 'Export to excel' then open the file and go back to the site and click 'Vessel At birth', 'Tools', 'Export to excel' and open that file, then use somthing like;

`Windows("Traffic.xls").Activate
    Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
    Sheets("Traffic").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Traffic").Move After:=Workbooks("Search Ship Schedule.xlsm").Sheets(4)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

To get the sheets from the workbooks back to my main workbook, where I will then search through and get the ones I want. Here's what I've got sofar;

```
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws2.Cells.ClearContents


Dim Site, BtnPage(1 To 2), Btn As String
Site = "https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/"
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate Site

        Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:3"))

ie.document.getElementById("Traffic").Click


        Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:3"))

ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ui-widget fg-button fg-button-icon-left ui-corner-all grid-tools")(0).Click
Sleep 100
ie.document.getElementById("0").Click

        Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

Sleep 2500

SendKeys "%o"

        Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
Sleep 6500

'Sleep_DoEvents 7

ie.document.getElementById("InPort").Click


Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:3"))

ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ui-widget fg-button fg-button-icon-left ui-corner-all grid-tools")(0).Click
Sleep 100
ie.document.getElementById("0").Click

        Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'Windows("Traffic").Activate
        'Application.Windows("Traffic.xls").ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
        'Application.Windows("Traffic.xls").Activate

        Static hWnds() As Variant
        Sleep 500
        r = FindWindowLike(hWnds(), 0, "Public Pages - Internet Explorer", "*", Null)

        Sleep 3000

        If r > 0 Then
            SetFocusAPI (hWnds(1))
            'Sleep 1000
            SendKeys "%o"
            Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Sleep 6000
            'Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
        End If
'ie.Close
```

and I have this in a module

```
Public Declare Function BlockInput Lib "USER32.dll" (ByVal fBlockIt As Long) As Long


#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

 Declare Function SetFocusAPI Lib "User32" Alias "SetForegroundWindow" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
   Declare Function GetWindow Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
   Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "User32" () As Long
   Declare Function GetWindowLW Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
   Declare Function GetParent Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
   Declare Function GetClassName Lib "User32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
   Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) _
     As Long

   Public Const GWL_ID = (-12)
   Public Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
   Public Const GW_CHILD = 5
   'FindWindowLike
   ' - Finds the window handles of the windows matching the specified
   '   parameters
   '
   'hwndArray()
   ' - An integer array used to return the window handles
   '
   'hWndStart
   ' - The handle of the window to search under.
   ' - The routine searches through all of this window's children and their
   '   children recursively.
   ' - If hWndStart = 0 then the routine searches through all windows.
   '
   'WindowText
   ' - The pattern used with the Like operator to compare window's text.
   '
   'ClassName
   ' - The pattern used with the Like operator to compare window's class
   '   name.
   '
   'ID
   ' - A child ID number used to identify a window.
   ' - Can be a decimal number or a hex string.
   ' - Prefix hex strings with "&H" or an error will occur.
   ' - To ignore the ID pass the Visual Basic Null function.
   '
   'Returns
   ' - The number of windows that matched the parameters.
   ' - Also returns the window handles in hWndArray()
   '
   '----------------------------------------------------------------------
   'Remove this next line to use the strong-typed declarations
   #Const WinVar = True
   #If WinVar Then
   Function FindWindowLike(hWndArray() As Variant, _
    ByVal hWndStart As Variant, WindowText As String, _
     Classname As String, ID) As Integer
   Dim hWnd
   Dim r
   Static level
   Static iFound
   #ElseIf Win32 Then
   Function FindWindowLike(hWndArray() As Long, ByVal hWndStart As Long, _
    WindowText As String, Classname As String, ID) As Long
   Dim hWnd As Long
   Dim r As Long
   ' Hold the level of recursion:
   Static level As Long
   ' Hold the number of matching windows:
   Static iFound As Long
   #ElseIf Win16 Then
   Function FindWindowLike(hWndArray() As Integer, _
    ByVal hWndStart As Integer, WindowText As String, _
    Classname As String, ID) As Integer
   Dim hWnd As Integer
   Dim r As Integer
   ' Hold the level of recursion:
   Static level As Integer
   'Hold the number of matching windows:
   Static iFound As Integer
   #End If
   Dim sWindowText As String
   Dim sClassname As String
   Dim sID
   ' Initialize if necessary:
   If level = 0 Then
   iFound = 0
   ReDim hWndArray(0 To 0)
   If hWndStart = 0 Then hWndStart = GetDesktopWindow()
   End If
   ' Increase recursion counter:
   level = level + 1
   ' Get first child window:
   hWnd = GetWindow(hWndStart, GW_CHILD)
   Do Until hWnd = 0
   DoEvents ' Not necessary
   ' Search children by recursion:
   r = FindWindowLike(hWndArray(), hWnd, WindowText, Classname, ID)
   ' Get the window text and class name:
   sWindowText = Space(255)
   r = GetWindowText(hWnd, sWindowText, 255)
   sWindowText = Left(sWindowText, r)
   sClassname = Space(255)
   r = GetClassName(hWnd, sClassname, 255)
   sClassname = Left(sClassname, r)
   ' If window is a child get the ID:
   If GetParent(hWnd) <> 0 Then
   r = GetWindowLW(hWnd, GWL_ID)
   sID = CLng("&H" & Hex(r))
   Else
   sID = Null
   End If
   ' Check that window matches the search parameters:
   If sWindowText Like WindowText And sClassname Like Classname Then
   If IsNull(ID) Then
   ' If find a match, increment counter and
   '  add handle to array:
   iFound = iFound + 1
   ReDim Preserve hWndArray(0 To iFound)
   hWndArray(iFound) = hWnd
   ElseIf Not IsNull(sID) Then
   If CLng(sID) = CLng(ID) Then
   ' If find a match increment counter and
   '  add handle to array:
   iFound = iFound + 1
   ReDim Preserve hWndArray(0 To iFound)
   hWndArray(iFound) = hWnd
   End If
   End If
   Debug.Print "Window Found: "
   Debug.Print "  Window Text  : " & sWindowText
   Debug.Print "  Window Class : " & sClassname
   Debug.Print "  Window Handle: " & CStr(hWnd)
   End If
   ' Get next child window:
   hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)
   Loop
   ' Decrement recursion counter:
   level = level - 1
   ' Return the number of windows found:
   FindWindowLike = iFound
   End Function
```

My problem is that when these excel files are opening, they open in a new instance of excel and I can't reference them any regular way. Since they are not actually saved I can't use GetObject() like recommended in this answer [Can VBA Reach Across Instances of Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971473/can-vba-reach-across-instances-of-excel) and I don't know how to reference the excel workbooks using a handle. I think that they are opening in a new instance of excel because the macro is running and even when using Sleep() it doesn't let excel open the new workbooks. I have tried using a Do DoWhile Loop to let excel open the workbooks but that doesn't seem to work. So, if anyone could help me open the workbooks in the same instance of excel so that I can reference them easier or reference between excel instances without GetObject() that would be greatly appreciated.

==================================EDIT=======================================

This was the final result I wound up with. Thanks to user3565396 I just saved it in the downloads folder like you recommended, I couldn't figure out how to use `WinHttp` like Robert Co recommended. For some reason the code exits without an error message on the line `wb2.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wb1.Sheets("Import")` but re-opening seems to work fine and it's only used once or twice a day.

```
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Integer

Function DelTrafficAndInPort()

'Clear all ws's like "Traffic" or "In Port" and all wb's

    'In VBE, click Tools, References, find "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
    'and check it off for this program to work
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim fold As Folder
    Dim f As File
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim cbo As Object

    folderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Downloads"

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set fold = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)

    For Each f In fold.Files
        If ((Left(f.Name, 7) = "Traffic" Or Left(f.Name, 7) = "In Port") And Right(f.Name, 4) = ".xls") Then
            fso.DeleteFile f.Path
        End If
    Next
End Function



Sub BtnScrape_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False


Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    Run DelTrafficAndInPort() ' from downloads

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
        If (Left(ws.Name, 7) = "Traffic" Or Left(ws.Name, 7) = "In Port") Then ws.Delete
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim ie As InternetExplorer 'SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim sw As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/"

Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

Dim BtnName(1 To 2), wbPath(1 To 2) As String
    BtnName(1) = "Traffic"
    BtnName(2) = "InPort"
    wbPath(1) = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Downloads\Traffic.xls" '"C:\Users\owner\Downloads\Traffic.xls"
    wbPath(2) = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Downloads\In Port.xls"

Dim I As Integer
For I = 1 To 2
    ie.document.getElementById(BtnName(I)).Click

    Do While Not ie.readyState = 4 Or ie.Busy
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(8).Click 'Tools
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    ie.document.getElementById("0").Click             'Export to Excel    'ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(27).Click
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:5"))

    SetForegroundWindow (ie.hwnd)
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "%S" 'Save
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(wbPath(I))
    wb2.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wb1.Sheets("Import")
    wb2.Close False
Next I
ie.Quit

wb1.Sheets("Import").Select

Run DelTrafficAndInPort() ' from downloads

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. I skipped some steps which you have done correctly. The code starts from clicking Tools and then Export to excel. After that I click "Alt + S" which is Save (Not Open). With this code I managed to copy worksheet from the downloaded file to the workbook from which I was running the VBA code. Hope that helps.

P.S. All files must be in the same directory.

```
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Integer

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim sw As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Sub test()
Dim hw As Long, rtrn As Integer
For Each ie In sw
    If ie.LocationURL = "https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/" Then
        ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")(8).Click 'Tools
        ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")(27).Click 'Export to Excel
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
        Exit For
    End If
Next ie
hw = ie.hwnd
rtrn = SetForegroundWindow(hw)
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
SendKeys "%S" 'Save
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
Workbooks.Open ("Traffic.xls")
Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("TEST.xlsb") 'Target Workbook
For Each sh In Workbooks("Traffic.xls").Worksheets
    sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I guess I was trying to avoid saving the file so that I wouldn't be accumulating the workbooks on the computer without the user realising. But it would be a lot easier (and quicker) to do it this way and delete the old workbooks.

Answer (score -1):

When you click a link, it download it to the browser temporary folder and open it with the recommended application in another session. The trick is is download the file within the VBA itself and open it in the same session. If the url is predictable, you can certainly automate that.

Use `WinHttp` to download as a stream and recreate that file in your own temp folder. It's about 10 lines of code. Continue the VBA with `Workbooks.Open` which opens the file in the same session.