# Find all open Word Applications from within a VBA EXCEL-Macro

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, ms-word

In an EXCEL-macro I want to copy a selected range to a WORD-document table. I know how to do this, creating a new WORD-document (target). But I want to check if there are already open WORD-documents from which I can select a target.

I found code for looping through all open EXCEL-Applications from within a EXCEL-Macro. I modified the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35343847/10268566) from *Florent Breheret* as given below.

What are the missing class names, indicated by "???" in the code, to look for WORD-documents?

Thank you in advance!  Immanuel

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As LongPtr

'Test my code
Private Sub GetWordInstances_Test()
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim i, cnt As Integer

    cnt = 0
    For Each wd In GetWordInstances()
        cnt = cnt + 1
        Debug.Print wd.Application.Name, cnt

        For i = 1 To wd.Documents.Count

            Debug.Print wd.Documents(i).FullName, i
        Next i
    Next
End Sub

'Getting open WORD instances from within EXCEL-VBA
Public Function GetWordInstances() As Collection
    Dim guid&(0 To 3), acc As Object, hwnd, hwnd2, hwnd3
    guid(0) = &H20400
    guid(1) = &H0
    guid(2) = &HC0
    guid(3) = &H46000000

    Set GetWordInstances = New Collection
    Do
        hwnd = FindWindowExA(0, hwnd, "OpusApp", vbNullString)
        If hwnd = 0 Then Exit Do

        hwnd2 = FindWindowExA(hwnd, 0, "???", vbNullString)

        hwnd3 = FindWindowExA(hwnd2, 0, "???", vbNullString)

        'hand over found WORD application to collection
        If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd3, &HFFFFFFF0, guid(0), acc) = 0 Then
            GetWordInstances.Add acc.Application
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers share a *specific* problem with their code. Only the section of code that is the problem should be included.  Please see **how to create a [mcve]**, as well as "[ask]". (Also, [here is a checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.)

Comment: Also, it seems a little counter-intuitive, but here is explanation of [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8112776).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will consider it for future questions and modified the post above (made it shorter, only one question). And "Can someone help me.." yeah, I see your point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374826/how-to-iterate-over-multiple-word-instances-with-accessibleobjectfromwindow/54393070#54393070) that explains the process to solve your question.

Resuming:

```
OpusApp ==> _WwF ==> _WwB ==> _WwG.
```

You must add another layer:

```
    hwnd = FindWindowExA(0, hwnd, "OpusApp", vbNullString)
    If hwnd = 0 Then Exit Do

    hwnd2 = FindWindowExA(hwnd, 0, "_WwF", vbNullString)

    hwnd3 = FindWindowExA(hwnd2, 0, "_WwB", vbNullString)

    hwnd4 = FindWindowExA(hwnd3, 0, "_WwG", vbNullString)
    'hand over found WORD application to collection
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd4, &HFFFFFFF0, guid(0), acc) = 0 Then
        GetWordInstances.Add acc.Application
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your support! That solves it for me. Good to know I was close :)
Cheers, Immanuel

Comment: @sky_pablo, if it solves to you, please mark as correct answer (the green check-mark); in this way all people looking for solution will know that there is actually an answer... and if you don't mind, you may too up-vote my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:
1. Add the reference in Excel: Tools->References->Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library
2. Run this code:

Sub openDocs()

```
Dim openDoc     As Word.Document
Dim docCount    As Long

docCount = Documents.Count

For Each openDoc In Documents
    'do whatever, i.e.:
    ' debug.print openDoc.Name
Next openDoc

If docCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no open documents."
Else
    MsgBox "There are " & docCount & " open documents."
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi Masovy, thanks for your answer. I actually tried a similar code above. Some how, it does not work consequently, meaning: Sometimes it works, some times it does not. That is way I thought of using Windows API methods. But I will keep researching the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this ...

```
Sub CheckForWordApp()
Dim wApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set wApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    'Word application is not running so create it
    Set wApp = New Word.Application
    wApp.Visible = True
    'no documents will exist, so do something
Else
    'A Word application exists, make sure it's visible
    wApp.Visible = True
    If wApp.Document.Count > 0 Then
        'There are open documents so do something
    Else
        'No documents are open so do something else
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: H Rich, thanks for the answer. I am a year late :) but thanks! I solved the problem with the Marcelo's answer (below).

But thanks for your support!
Immanuel