# How to close all anonym, running Excel applications without killing

Tags: c#, excel-interop, comobject

Our robotics software has problems to interact with MS Excel, when
the last session was killed. Ok, the problem ocures, when there
are recovery files available and I could fix that problem, by
deactivating autosave.
UIPath - our robotics software, bases on .Net - does not always close the excel.application
correctly after the interaction or better - I cannot guaranty, that there is not running excel task.
The task may also be started by UIPath itself.

I want to write an activity, that surely closes all excel instances
without killing - `p.Kill()` - them.

The function has no input and no output.

It looks like this:

```
    public static class ExcelCleaner
{
    private const string __EXCELAPP_REGKEY = "Excel.Application";
    private const string __EXCEL_TASKNAME = "EXCEL";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (ExcelRunning())
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExApp = null;

            ExApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(__EXCELAPP_REGKEY) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
            if (ExApp == null) { throw new System.NullReferenceException("Error - Unable to attach " + __EXCELAPP_REGKEY + " !"); }

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WB in ExApp.Workbooks)
            {
                WB.Close(false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
                if (WB != null) { System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(WB); }
            }

            ExApp.Application.Quit();
            if (ExApp.Application != null) { System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExApp.Application); }

            try
            {
                ExApp.Quit();
            }
            catch{ }
            finally {
                if (ExApp != null) { System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ExApp); }
            }

            System.GC.Collect();
            System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }

    private static bool ExcelRunning() { if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(__EXCEL_TASKNAME).Length > 0) { return true; } return false; }
}
```

Running one Excel task, that code closes excel correctly, but the task is still available and the `While`loop is never escaped. A running Excel task is a bad situation for the next excel access of our robotics software.

The problem is, I do not know about `Excel - Com-Objects`, that are referenced in UIPath, as the robotics software uses the `Excel.Interop.Office.Excel` Com-Interface, but its a blackbox.

Comment: Sounds like you know how to close Excel, but you don't know [how to enumerate running  Excel instances and get their Application object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363748/having-multiple-excel-instances-launched-how-can-i-get-the-application-object-f) in order to close them.

Comment: Thank you, but is that really necessary? Can one use p.Handle() or something like that to enumerate? What is "XLMAIN" and "XLDESK"? What handle do they give the name?