# Excel Workbook open status

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if any excel instance is open or not. I want it to be dynamic like if I have multiple excel workbooks open so it should return the names of all the opened workbooks.

Comment: Will you be running the vba from Excel?

Comment: @Solar Mike from AutoCAD VBA

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363748/having-multiple-excel-instances-launched-how-can-i-get-the-application-object-f