# Macro between 3 Excel Instances

Tags: excel, vba, instance, power-automate

I am trying to run a Macro between 3 workbooks through Power Automate. Since I launch the workbooks through Power Automate they are being run in 3 different instances(I dont know why). That is why Macro cant be applied between 3 different instances. Do you have any solution, idea about that? Would be pleased from your help. Thank you.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8422953)

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363748/having-multiple-excel-instances-launched-how-can-i-get-the-application-object-f   "run a macro between 3 workbooks" is a bit unclear though.

Comment: Are you meaning Power Automate Desktop?  PowerAutomate can't run macros, it's not supported in Excel online so I figure you're meaning PAD.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try opening one file from PAD and running a macro that will open the other 2 files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Martin. I guess you mean Power Automate Desktop by PAD. Actually this is an alternative but through PAD it is not so accurate each time to perform this task because there are many inputs(mouse movements, clicks etc.) That is why primarily I need a fixed scripts like Macro.

Comment: With PAD I did mean Power Automate Desktop.   However, if you are not using PAD I'm not sure how you are actually running macros. 

Alse using PAD does not require to use clicks and mouse movements.
You have built in actions that allow you to open an excel file and run a Macro using VBA.  From that Macro you open other workbooks that will bu opened in the same instance.