# How to select and pass workbook names that are open in different instance?

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-instances

I'm trying  to develop an excel file that contains VBA to manipulate and adjust repots that are excel files generated from SQL Server using Excel-Macro Enabled Template. The excel that contains the VBA has a List Box to shows all excel files that are open and a text box for the selected report, as shown in the attached picture. [image: the main excel file] The 1st problem I faced was to display excel report that are open in a different instance of Excel. I posted a question and I got an answer, attached link, [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73559304/workbook-name-property-does-not-return-the-name-of-an-excel-file), that solved the problem and open excel files can be shown in the List Box. The problem now is, how can I pass the name of the selected report (workbook name) to subs and functions to become the file that will be manipulated using the VBA code?  I tried this way `Sel_Rpt = Sheet1.TextBox1.Value` and then `Set Rpt = Workbooks(Sel_Rpt).Worksheets("Report")`,  but it didn't work.

Comment: Keep a reference to each workbook object and pass the selected reference to your subs instead of just passing the workbook name

Comment: `GetObject("Filename and path")` switches to the open file (it will be registered in the ROT (Running Object Table)) or if not open opens the file.

Comment: @TimWilliams , Could you please explain more or give details or example? thanks

Comment: You don't show any code, so it's difficult to make a useful suggestion here.