SAP Excel extract files which open up after macro ran through the code
My problem is that the exported Excel files open after the macro is finished. I couldn't solve the problem with the other articles. Has anybody an idea?
I tried multiple prompts to close the files but nothing worked out.
The best would be if it wouldn't open itself.
Sub Makro()
Dim SapGuiAuto, Application, Connection, session As Object

 ' First I just open SAP and insert the string'

    session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "C:\\TEMP"
    session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX"
    session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").Press
    session.findById("wnd[1]").Close
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").Press
           
        Range("B3").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Open ("C:\\TEMP\EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX")
        Windows("EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX").Activate
        Set mp = Range("B3")
        eintragmp = Mid(mp.Value, 1, 2)
        Windows("SAP Verknüpfung.xlsx").Activate
        Cells(i, 6) = eintragmp
          
        
        Workbooks("EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX").Close SaveChanges:=False
        ' filePath = "C:\TEMP\EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX"
        ' If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then
        ' Kill filePath
       
           
Else
Windows("SAP Verknüpfung.xlsx").Activate
Cells(i, 6) = "Fertig"
If Cells(i, 6) = "Fertig" Then
Cells(i, 7) = "Umlauf"
End If
   
End If
On Error GoTo 0
 
Next i
 
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").Press
 
 
Set Application = Nothing
Set session = Nothing
Set Connection = Nothing
End Sub


Are the exported files open in a different instance of Excel?  Can you see them in the project explorer in your VBA editor for example?

See https://community.sap.com/t5/supply-chain-management-q-a/prevent-or-close-exported-files-from-sap-gui-to-excel/qaq-p/12559478 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683132/how-can-i-use-vba-to-close-workbooks-opened-in-a-separate-instance-of-excel

Based on my understanding and experience, there isn't a known method or feature within SAP that allows users to prevent the system from automatically opening a file after it has been exported.
My approach to closing the exported file after the export is as follows
Sub Makro
 ' The variable xlfile should contain the filename but not the complete path
 ' in your case it is probably "EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX"
 Dim xlfile as string
  ' Code to download the file 
  runCloseWorkbook xlFile, 0
End Sub

The procedure runCloseWorkbook will attempt to close the workbook a certain number of times. Typically, the download of an Excel file from SAP runs asynchronously while the VBA code continues to execute. Therefore, the code tries to search all Excel instances for an open workbook named xlfile and attempts to close it. If the file is not found, it will retry after five seconds. The code will stop this process after 10 attempts. This approach works quite well in my case.
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
    ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
    (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
    ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long
         
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Const S_OK As Long = &H0
Private Const IID_IDispatch As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM As Long = &HFFFFFFF0

Sub runCloseWorkbook(wkbName As String, counter As Long)
    
    Const MAX_TRIES As Long = 10
        
    If closeWorkbook(wkbName) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter <= MAX_TRIES Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "'runCloseWorkbook """ & wkbName & """,""" & counter & "'"
        End If
    End If
       
End Sub

Function closeWorkbook(wkbName As String) as Boolean
    
    Dim hWinXL As Long
    hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    
    Do While hWinXL > 0
                
        If getXLApp(hWinXL, xlApp) Then
            For Each wb In xlApp.Workbooks
                If wb.Name = wkbName Then
                    wb.Close False
                    closeWorkbook = True
                    ' xlApp.Quit
                End If
            Next
        End If
        hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0, hWinXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    Loop
    
End Function

Function getXLApp(hWinXL As Long, xlApp As Excel.Application) As Boolean
    ' Function GetXLApp(hWinXL As Long, xlApp As Object) As Boolean
    
    Dim hWinDesk As Long, hWin7 As Long
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim iid As GUID
    
    Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iid)
    hWinDesk = FindWindowEx(hWinXL, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
    hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
    
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iid, obj) = S_OK Then
        Set xlApp = obj.Application
        getXLApp = True
    End If

End Function

You probably need to replace the line
Workbooks("EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX").Close SaveChanges:=False

in your code with the line
  runCloseWorkbook "EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX", 0


Thanks for the quick answer. I just replaced the line but it failed because runCloseWorkbook is not defined as Sub or Function. Do I have to add something to make this run?

Yes, of course. You have to add all the code I posted. There is the Sub runcloseWorkbook defined.

Also that stuff? Option Explicit
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
(ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long
Private Type GUID
Data1 As Long
Data2….  Because that doesn’t work for me

doesn’t work for me is not a good description. In case you have a MAC the code posted will not be a solution for you at all. In case you have a 64-bit Office (Attention: Windows is 64bit, I am talking abot Office!!) you have to adjust the code, that's right.

You can have a look here

I found another way to solve the problem, Set xlApp = GetObject("C:\TEMP\EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX").Application
Windows("EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX").Activate
xlApp.Workbooks("EXPORT_" & i & ".XLSX").Close False
xlApp.Quit. Made that the windows diddnt open up.

But I have another problem. At Itererator i = 8 or sometimes later at  i =12 ther ecomes an pop up windwow which says: "PERSONAL.XLSB" is locked for editing by 'Wellinger, Malte (028)'. Click on 'Read Only' or 'Notify' to open the document in read-only mode and receive a notification when it becomes available. does anybody know why this occurs and how to solve this?

Sorry, you use another way to tackle the problem. In that case I'd suggest to edit your post accordingly or even create another one.
