Macro/VBA Code stopped working since upgrade to Microsoft 365
First off, I am very much an amateur with regards to VBA and have inherited a file from someone who has left the company.
They had set up a code/macro that would pull a report from SAP and then this would be used to compare the previous data and update the list. It was an inventory of material in a stock location.
The macros manage to pull the report no problem. It saves the report when generated, but it hangs up at the following point.
'wait until export workbook is loaded so the first sheet can be re-named  
Do Until ActiveWorkbook.Name = "EXPORT.XLSX"  
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00")) 
    ' the slowest download time seems to be 10 seconds, J Bell failed @ home with c. 30 seconds 
    Workbooks("EXPORT.XLSX").Activate 
    On Error GoTo 0 
Loop

The purpose of this is to start sorting the file named export by date, but it doesn't get to that point.
All that is open at this point is the original creator sheet and the workbook entitled Export.xlsx.
Everything was working fine until I was upgraded yesterday.
The time was set to Now + Timevalue ("0:00:10") at first, in case it was needing more time.
Any help is appreciated
What I expected to happen is the file Export.xlsx is sorted by date. It seems like its something to do with the active workbook

"wait until export workbook is loaded" - can you check manually are you able to get the export and in which time?

Sounds like the report may be opening in a different instance of Excel from the one where your code is running ?

Do you know the full path to "Export.xlsx" ?

@rotabot the export pops up no problem and within the time.

@Tim William - yes, its opening a different instance of EXCel from the one where my code is running

Then you can try using GetObject("fullPathToExportedXlsx") to reference the file

...or for something more flexible take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35343847/478884

Here's one way to deal with potentially multiple instances of Excel:
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As LongPtr

Sub Tester()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = WaitForWorkbook("Temp.xlsx", 30)
    
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Got '" & wb.Name & "'"
        'work with `wb`
    Else
        Debug.Print "Wait timed out"
    End If

End Sub


Function WaitForWorkbook(wbName As String, Optional WaitForSeconds As Long = 30) As Workbook
    Dim xl As Application, t, wb As Workbook
    t = Timer
    Do While Timer - t < WaitForSeconds
        For Each xl In GetExcelInstances()
            For Each wb In xl.Workbooks
                If wb.Name = wbName Then
                    Set WaitForWorkbook = wb
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next wb
        Next
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function

Public Function GetExcelInstances() As Collection
  Dim guid&(0 To 3), acc As Object, hwnd, hwnd2, hwnd3
  guid(0) = &H20400
  guid(1) = &H0
  guid(2) = &HC0
  guid(3) = &H46000000

  Set GetExcelInstances = New Collection
  Do
    hwnd = FindWindowExA(0, hwnd, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    If hwnd = 0 Then Exit Do
    hwnd2 = FindWindowExA(hwnd, 0, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
    hwnd3 = FindWindowExA(hwnd2, 0, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd3, &HFFFFFFF0, guid(0), acc) = 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore error on duplicate key
        GetExcelInstances.Add acc.Application, CStr(acc.Application.hwnd)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
  Loop
End Function


Thanks for this. I'm not very proficient at coding. Could you confirm are there any instances in this code where I would need to reference the workbooks that have been created. I.e. Export.xlxs ?
Which parts need to be tailored to my own drive/pathway?

In the sub Tester it's waiting for a workbook named "Temp.xlsx" to be open in Excel.  If you know the name of the workbook you need to work on, put that name instead, and do your formatting using the returned wb reference.
