# Excel VBA Counting and Storing List of All Open Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, count

I am looking to try and count the current number of workbooks that are opened. `Workbooks.Count` will not work because not all of the files are in the same Excel application instance. When the file is opened after being downloaded, its in a new instance of excel, so `Workbooks` does not include it.

Is there a way to get the count of all workbooks for every instance of Excel that is running?

Comment: I have replaced that with Windows.Count too, did not work.

Comment: Try `for each b in application.workbooks`

Comment: I tried `For Each b In Application.Workbooks
        MsgBox (CStr(b.Name))
    Next b` but no luck, stil only shows the workbook with the button.

Comment: Are the workbooks open in different applications?  (For example, often a downloaded workbook will open up in a completely different excel application)

Comment: @Demetri Yes. Can it not count them if its different excels that are open? If not is there a way to make it get all of them if this happens?

Comment: You are right. When I opened them all under 1 Excel application it counts them all. There has to be a way to get the workbooks from all open applications.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easy way to count the workbooks when they are in different applications.  There may be a way using functions that look at windows, but they are quite advanced.  (FindWindowEx, GetWindowText, GetClassName)

Comment: OK I will revise my question to ask this.

Comment: Should add that rather important comment to OP...

Comment: Check [here](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T009452_Finding_Other_Instances_of_Excel_in_a_Macro.html)

Comment: Found this as a good answer. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3303016/2131749)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example how it can be done (no API):

```
Public Function ListAllExcelWB(Optional ByVal SearchFor$) As Variant() 'exept this one
On Error Resume Next

 If SearchFor = vbNullString Then SearchFor = "*.*"

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Status As Long
Dim Arr()
ReDim Arr(1 to 2, 1 To 100)
Dim i&

Do
  Err.Clear
  Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  Status = Err.Number
  If Status = 0 Then
      'xl.Visible = True
      For Each Wb In xl.Workbooks
            With Wb
                  If .Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
                    i = i + 1
                    Arr(1, i) = .Name 
                    Arr(2, i) = .Path & "\" & .Name
                    If i > 99 Then Status = 1
                  Else: Status = 1 'stoppe la loop si se trouve soi meme, car au niveau des stack, l'instance active est la derniere
                  End If
            End With
      Next

  End If
Loop Until Status <> 0 '= 429

If i > 0 Then
      ReDim Preserve Arr(1 to 2,1 To i)
Else: Erase Arr 'ReDim Arr(0 To 0)
End If

Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

Set xl = Nothing: Set Wb = Nothing
ListAllExcelWB = Arr
Erase Arr
End Function
```

Comment: Friendly hint: you redimmed Arr(1 To 100, 1 To 2), but assign your 1-100 items to the 2nd dimension; think this to be correct:   `Arr(i, 1) = .Name` and `Arr(i, 2) = .Path & "\" & .Name`. BTW `SearchFor$` is not needed in this example.

Comment: yeah, i know, it was re-used code that i changed to my needs, the outcome had to be index in first dimension, wich is not practical generaly speaking because of redim not working unless last dimension.