# VBA Set Excel.Application Object to already open workbook instead of creating a new Excel instance

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following all the time to manipulate Excel data from Access.

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Object")
```

However, this method creates a new Excel instance and only applies formatting, for example, to it.

```
xl.Range(...).Interior.Color = blah, blah, blah
```

Will only refer to that instance of an Excel object that was create with the first line of code.

The problem I am having is that I already have an instance of Excel open and there is VBA in Access that I want to use to apply formatting to the already open file to prep it for importing. I guess I could create the new instance of Excel and just refer to the workbook I am working on with `xl.Workbook(blah).Activate` but that seems kinda messy.

Yea, I could move the code to Excel, but that defeats the purpose of manipulating Excel from Access and having my VBA in central location accessible to users.

Comment: Look into `GetObject()`   As long as there's only a single instance of Excel already open, it should do what you want.

Comment: Maybe this can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971473/can-vba-reach-across-instances-of-excel

Comment: Does Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") fit the bill? This gets excel if it's open.

Comment: If you know the full name of the workbook, use that with `GetObject` and then it won't matter how many instances of Excel are already open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using:

```
set xl = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
```