# VBA macro across the Excel instances

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Good Afternoon,

I have a problem with VBA macro.
I am trying to download data automatically (with macro) from some SAP software. All is going well to situation when downloaded data are exported to Excel file.
I cannot "reach" this workbook with macro cause of error:

> Subscript out of range

The reason is that excel sheet is an another instance of Excel.

I do not have a problem with others SAP download files where they are in the same Excel instances.

How can I connect with the second instance of Excel?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please show the relevant code to make this a [mcve]. Why is your macro creating another instance of Excel?

Comment: SAP creating new instance of excel - not macro (when downloading data to excel)

Comment: See the lower-most example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/getobject-function . Other than that, refer to John's comment - SO isn't a code-writing service, but we can help with fixing code that isn't working.

Comment: You may start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971473/can-vba-reach-across-instances-of-excel.

Comment: I need to connect with another excel instance by VBA (the second instance is not created by me) and makes some actions on this workbook.